# Left join operation in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I have two datasets with a common key column and I want to perform left join operation. Is there any corresponding function in apache beam that performs the left join operation in apache beam ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small library of joins available in Beam Java SDK, see if the implementation works for you: [`org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.joinlibrary.Join`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.html), [`source`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/join-library/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.java#L94)

**Update**

You can implement it yourself with similar approach, utilizing [`CoGroupByKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey):
 - put both `PCollections` into a [`KeyedPCollectionTuple`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/join/KeyedPCollectionTuple.html);
 - apply a [`CoGroupByKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/join/CoGroupByKey.html) which will group elements from both `PCollections` per key per window;
 - apply a `ParDo` which loops over the results of a `CoGroupByKey`, joins left and right record one at a time, and emits the results (see the [`CoGroupByKey` example in the Beam Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey));

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19012408)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point. The poster asks whether Beam has an implementation of the left join. I provided a link to the function in the Beam SDK which is literally called `leftOuterJoin()`. How does this not answer the question? There is possibility that this specific implementation of join may not satisfy author's specific requirements (there is not a lot of details in the question), hence the comment to see if it works for him. I did not ask for clarifications.

Comment: Above is the default message posted when your answer is marked as "not providing an answer" or "should be a comment". Also, in your case the answer looks like a "link answer" which links to an external resource that may change any moment. You would need to include important details into your answer, so that if the link is broken, the answer may still provide enough details to answer the question. If you follow the last link in the automated message I've posted and look for "clarification" it says: **Generally, truly important information should be incorporated into an answer anyway**

Comment: I see. Thank you for the guidance. Updated the response a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Example of left outer join:

```java
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.joinlibrary.Join;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestJoin {

    @Test
    public void left_join_example() {
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
        PCollection<KV<Integer, String>> leftCollection = pipeline.apply(Create.of(KV.of(1, "a"), KV.of(2, "b"), KV.of(3, "c")));
        PCollection<KV<Integer, Integer>> rightCollection = pipeline.apply(Create.of(KV.of(1, 1), KV.of(1, 10), KV.of(2, 2), KV.of(4, 4)));
        PCollection<KV<Integer, KV<String, Integer>>> leftJoinCollection = Join.leftOuterJoin(leftCollection, rightCollection, 0);

        PAssert.that(leftJoinCollection).containsInAnyOrder(KV.of(1, KV.of("a" , 1)), KV.of(1, KV.of("a" , 10)),
                KV.of(2, KV.of("b", 2)), KV.of(3, KV.of("c", 0)));

        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
}
```